# Marketing cloud sub-domain

Tags: marketing-cloud

How i can find the sales-force Marketing cloud sub-domain ?
I was trying to use the sub domain for API call purposes but i am not able to find the sub-domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the endpoints? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/wsdl-endpoint-links.htm

The Salesforce documentation is a good place to start before you post questions on stack exchange.

The SubDomain you are referring to are automatically generated when you create an Installed Package. **Administration > Account > Installed Package**

[image: installed package]

Comment: Hello, Jackson Thanks for this help.
Please see below They mention " YOUR_SUBDOMAIN" what this means? where I can get this Subdomain, 

 WSDL Links for Your Tenant
All instances: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/etframework.wsdl

Sandbox instance: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.soap-test.marketingcloudsandboxapis.com/etframework.wsdl

Comment: Admin settings > cloud preferences or security

Comment: Thanks Jackson!
We are looking for 28 digit subdomain number as given in below example 

For example, Northern Trail Outfitters’ tenant has this subdomain: mc563885gzs27c5t9-63k636ttgm. These are their endpoints:

REST API endpoint: mc563885gzs27c5t9-63k636ttgm.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
SOAP API endpoint: mc563885gzs27c5t9-63k636ttgm.soap.marketingcloudapis.com

Comment: I've updated my answer. Administration > Account > Installed Package

Answer (score 0):

Use this doc to help locate your TSE:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/your-subdomain-tenant-specific-endpoints.htm

TL;DR when you create an installed package to get clientid/secert it provides your subdomain

Comment: Thanks Eazye
We are looking for 28 digit subdomain number as given in below example For example, Northern Trail Outfitters’ tenant has this subdomain: mc563885gzs27c5t9-63k636ttgm. These are their endpoints: REST API endpoint: mc563885gzs27c5t9-63k636ttgm.rest.marketingcloudapis.com SOAP API endpoint: mc563885gzs27c5t9-63k636ttgm.soap.marketingcloudapis.co

Comment: when you create an installed package to get clientid/secert it provides your subdomain. You create a package by go to administrator > Account > Installed packages. Create a Package then add an API component.

alternatively you can go to  administrator > Account > account settings and it shows you your SOAP endpoint/wsdl

Answer (score 0):

Updating this answer for 2023. You can view the WSDL URL at https://your-friendly-admin-subdomain.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/WebServices/home